# Train data of synonyms word English with opennlp

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, opennlp

I'm sorry, I'm newbie in NLP.
I'm using opennlp to create AI for find synonyms word into raw text and show them to website.
Example : If I press : I go to school, AI will show me "go to" synonyms with "get to"...., and "school" synonyms with "University" or "High School"
I try use named entity recognition for this purpose but It unpossible..
Can anyone help me for this ??

Answer (score 1):

You will need a synonym dictionary, or train a [Word2Vec](https://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec) model for it.

How OpenNLP can help? It can help you preparing you dataset with a [sentence detector](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.sentdetect) and [tokenizer](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.tokenizer). You can also use it to search the terms you are interested in finding synonyms, like nouns and verbs, using the [part-of-speech tagger](http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.0/manual/opennlp.html#tools.postagger).

Comment: Thank you, I understand.. I will try your way :) I will review when I tried this

Comment: I tried your way, but Word2Vec don't understand between "book" for Noun and "book" for verb, I try train it but can't

Comment: Did you try different configuration? According to the vectors size and window your model will learn different aspects of the training data. Also, you need a huge training dataset (like wikipedia dump or news dumps).

Comment: Yes, I tries use Word2Vec to train WordNet Dictionary, but I can't fing anyway to train Word2Vec model for my purpose, I read document for it but can't find any way to config data.. can you help me, give me some information